# Custom directive tag not triggering directive code, in angularjs 1.2.29

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use an element directive (restrict: "E") to define a custom component. Here's my **page.html** template, which gets pulled into **index.html** via  the `ng-view` directive:

```
<eng-popup>This text appears, but is rendered in a span</eng-popup>
```

Angular IS running; **index.html** has the `ng-app="templatesApp"` directive in the body tag and **app.js** sets up the module as below:

```
var app = angular.module("templatesApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

Further along, in **app.js** I have the popup directive defined:

```
app.directive('engPopup', function() {
    console.log("This console log does not trigger. I have tried 'eng-popup' as the directive's first parameter, but that doesn't work either.");
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        template: '<div id="thisDoesNotEvenAppear"></div>'
    };
});
```

The problem is, when I look at the resultant html of the component, it looks like this:

```
<span class="ng-scope" jQuery110209261664696867675="7">This text should appear, surely</span>
</eng-popup class="ng-scope" jQuery110209261664696867675="8"><//eng-popup>
```

**So I have a few questions:**

Why does the eng-popup directive `console.log` call NOT get triggered?

Why does the content in the eng-popup tag end up in a `span`?

And most mysteriously of all, why does the eng-popup tag start with an END tag and end with a tag with 2 slashes?

Finally, what am I messing up, to make this all happen?

**EDIT**
As requested, here's a Plunker. It looks like the span and end-tag issues are not happening in this simplified version, but the eng-popup directive is still not being triggered:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mVa6Mye5besJAtWihMWF?p=preview

**RE-EDIT**
Just in case this is still solvable, here's the latest Plunkr I've been able to put together. It's not working, which it at least has in common with our real project. Not sure if it's the same problem though.
https://plnkr.co/edit/sJoYnYjqx9ZGIH0KhObC

Comment: Please add plunker with given angular version

Comment: I removed the ngRoute in your plucker code as u haven't defined the dependency. And added some text inside the template eg. <div id="thisDoesNotEvenAppear">ABC</div> . It is working perfectly by displaying 'ABC'.The console log is directed to the browser console. Check by inspecting chrome. Pls elaborate the exact problem.

Comment: It seems to work in Plunkr (see my comment on Thor's answer below). Unfortunately I'm not able to emulate all of the files we're using in our actual project on Plunkr. The exact problem is that, when running in our project, the 'engPopup' directive does not get triggered, and the above detailed oddities occur (eng-popup content in span tag and eng-popup tags rendered incorrectly - start == end tag and end tag has extra slash. Please see resultant html code, above)

Comment: As far as I can tell, I've added in all the relevant files to this plunkr... https://plnkr.co/edit/sJoYnYjqx9ZGIH0KhObC?p=preview  If you click on 'next' it doesn't go to page1. Not sure what's happening there. Slightly running out of patience with it for today, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your example a bit (very little), and it seems to work OK?

https://plnkr.co/edit/3NlHNDOCBVRktk3ZcsnV?p=preview

What i've done is, remove the `ui-router` requirement, since you had not added the script reference. After that, it works. So, are you including `ui-router` in your project properly?

Comment: The added level of complication for my real-world project is that we set up the routes in app.config. When I take out the 'ngRoute' from my app module, nothing works. You mention ui-router; We're using ngRoute. Is that a problem?

Comment: I guess the question is, then: How would I correctly include ui-router in my project?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. In our project we include a link to angular-route.min.js. I've added something correlating to that in this plunk... https://plnkr.co/edit/sJoYnYjqx9ZGIH0KhObC?p=preview and it seems to be working. Not sure what the problem is with our real, more complex project, which is the thing I'm actually trying to fix. But thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

So a colleague has pointed out it 'works' in Chrome. Turns out it's an IE8 issue. Who would have thought... 
(The whole reason we're using 1.2.29 is because many of our users will be accessing it via IE8, but it looks like custom directives are off the table).